# filter different values in the same column

Tags: r

I have a 2018 Premier League dataset and Im trying to work to practise. I want to take Arsenal and Chelsea data but I cant. It works with the age, but it doesnt with "Chelsea" and "Arsenal"

```
CheArs <- premier %>% filter(Current Club == "Chelsea", Current Club == "Arsenal"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `filter` with or ( the OR operator is denoted with `|`), so a good idea is to use `dplyr` and do:

```
library(dplyr)

CheArs <- premier %>%
    filter(Current Club == "Chelsea"| Current Club == "Arsenal")
```

Which will give you a new dataframe with only information about Chelsea or Arsenal

Comment: did you load the library ```dplyr```? Maybe you need to install it first by doing ```install.packages('dplyr')```

Comment: Probably to do with what looks like a space in name of column you are trying to filter on. Check colnames (premier)

Comment: Thank you both, was a bad '!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is space bar in the column name. You need to use backticks or regular double quotes like this:

```
premier=tibble(`Current Club`=c("Arsenal","Chelsea"),Matches=c(5,10))
premier %>% filter(`Current Club`=="Arsenal"|`Current Club` == "Chelsea")
```

And next problem is the comma in filter if you want logical `OR` you need to use `|` operator instead of the comma